# File not found on iOS device, but found in Simulator

Tags: ios

When I run my application on the simulator I found the path of file using following code:

```
{

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
        NSLog(@"%@",basePath);
}
```

**simulator output:**

```
file:///Users/username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/E7816FF6-7E6A-4606-917E-E74CDB574EC8/Documents/images/20140306113538.png
```

And same code when I run in my device I found output with:

**Device output:**

```
file:///var/mobile/Applications/2D86A03F-C239-4B57-849F-019BCDCA8543/Documents/images/20140306114536.png
```

And when I checked, file was store in documents.
When I load this url in browser with path of simulator(which I get from simulator output) is loaded in browser.
But path of device(which I get from device output) it showing error in browser with file not found.

like: Firefox can't find the file at `/var/mobile/Applications/2D86A03F-C239-4B57-849F-019BCDCA8543/Documents/image/20140306114536.png.`

Only just because of this reason I am not able to send file from my device on my server using web service.

Xcode Version: 5.0.2

Device: iPhone 4(iOS 7.0.6)

Any One please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are trying to load file from your device which is not available on your system.
And your simulator directory is exist on your system thats why its loading file from your system.

So its better you can browse files from your device and copy into your system using following software

[iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/)

Comment: Yes I am already checked this using iExplorer. But I am not able to send this file on my server for upload image in server. Its given error file does not exist.

Comment: can you please show code how you are trying to check existence of file

Comment: Thank you... issue is resolved with remove file:///XXX from path at the time of posting in server.

Answer (score 0):

Why do your **folder names different** ?

for simulator it is "images" and for device it is "image".

Also closely **check case sensitivity**, since I also had faced similar problem for asset names. **MAC** file system searches with **case insensitivity** so simulator may be finding this file. Whereas **iOS device** file system is **case-sensitive**.

Comment: Its my spelling mistake when I write the question. Thank You.